# autohotkey search for a partial match

Tags: list, combobox, match, autohotkey

Can someone help with my code searching for a partial match. I seem to be stuck here.

I would like type only the first few letters in a combo-box, hit enter, and store whatever I have typed as a variable. Then I want to check my variable against my list for the closest name that matches what I have typed. That becomes the new variable. How do I do this?

```
#singleInstance, Force

list =
(
Phone Numbers
Important People
Modification
Traffic Data
Tasks
Tracker
)
Gui, +alwaysontop
Gui +Delimiter`n
Gui, Add, ComboBox, vMyVar w200 h110 CHOOSE1 sort, % LIST
Gui, Add, Button, gGO Default x+5 w60 h20 , GO
Gui, show, y200, What do you want now?!
return

; Type first couple letters in box hit enter

GO:
Gui, Submit, nohide
Loop, parse, List, `n
{
; Search LIST for nearest match
;First partial match found
; MyVar := "A_loopfield"
MsgBox % InStr(A_loopfield, DoThis)
}

if MyVar = Phone Numbers
; Msgbox or Function ETC..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
#singleInstance, Force

list =
(
Phone Numbers
Important People
Modification
Traffic Data
Tasks
Tracker
)
Gui, +alwaysontop
Gui +Delimiter`n
Gui, Add, ComboBox, vMyVar w200 h110 CHOOSE1 sort, % LIST
Gui, Add, Button, gGO Default x+5 w60 h20 , GO
Gui, show, y200, What do you want now?!
return

; Type first couple letters in box hit enter

GO:
Gui, Submit, nohide
GuiControlGet, text_typed,, ComboBox1
StringLen, length, text_typed ; retrieves the count of how many characters are  in the text typed
Loop, parse, List, `n
{
    If (SubStr(A_LoopField, 1, length) = text_typed)
    {
        GuiControl, Choose, MyVar, %A_LoopField%
        If (A_LoopField = "Phone Numbers")
            MsgBox, Item 1
        ; ...
        If (A_LoopField = "Traffic Data")
            MsgBox, Item 6
                break   
    }
}
return
```

Comment: Hey that's excellent. I also like the GuiControl. I didn't even think to use that. Nice touch.

Comment: Can you upvote me? I just need one more reputation so I can upvote others.